# sound profile change/volume change listener in blackberry

Tags: java, audio, blackberry

I want to make an application that listen to the sound profile change/volume change in blackberry. Targeting versions are 5,6,7
I had search in documentation of Blackberry but found nothing.
two things i found during searching.

1. globaleventlistener
   This needs GUID of that event, this event is not [documented](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800620/What_Is_-_System_Global_Events.html?nodeid=1163085&vernum=0) in event GUID list.
2. Notification manager
   Notificationmanager might help with one of the register.
   but i dont know how to register it with system events. It also needs GUID.

please share resource if i missed something. 
I am new to blackberry development. please help me out.

Thanks, 
Parth Shah

Answer (score 0):

```
package mypackage;

import net.rim.device.api.system.Application;
import net.rim.device.api.system.ApplicationDescriptor;
import net.rim.device.api.system.ApplicationManager;
import net.rim.device.api.system.Characters;
import net.rim.device.api.system.GlobalEventListener;
import net.rim.device.api.system.KeyHandlerRegistry;
import net.rim.device.api.system.KeyHandlerRegistryException;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Keypad;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;

/**
 * This class extends the UiApplication class, providing a
 * graphical user interface.
 */
public class MyApp extends Application
{
    /**
     * Entry point for application
     * @param args Command line arguments (not used)
     */ 
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Create a new instance of the application and make the currently
        // running thread the application's event dispatch thread.
        MyApp theApp = new MyApp(); 
        theApp.enterEventDispatcher();

    }


/**
 * Creates a new MyApp object
 */
public MyApp()
{        

    //Attach the keylistener to handle buttons pressed  
    addKeyListener(new Logger());

    super.addGlobalEventListener(new GlobalListener());
    try {
          //Any Keypad Button will work to catch everything
        KeyHandlerRegistry.register(getApplication(), Keypad.KEY_CONVENIENCE_1);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyHandlerRegistryException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}  

class GlobalListener implements GlobalEventListener{

    public void eventOccurred(long guid, int data0, int data1, Object object0,
            Object object1) {
                    //will catch and output all Global events to console
        System.out.println("[GLOBAL LISTENER] Event = "+guid);

    }

}
```

}

This should handle what you both are looking for.
As for the custom keyListner:

```
package mypackage;


import net.rim.device.api.system.Characters;
import net.rim.device.api.system.EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent;
import net.rim.device.api.system.KeyListener;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Keypad;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;


public final class Logger implements KeyListener {
//Set return to false to allow the program to pass the data to next keylistner
//All output to the console.
//Yet from testing only KeyUp and KeyDown are ever called and handle all special buttons 
//Volume, Dial, EndCall, etc...
    public boolean keyChar(char key, int status, int time) {
        System.out.println("CHAR PRESSED: <"+key+"/>");
        return false;
    }

    public boolean keyDown(int keycode, int time) {
        System.out.println("KEY PRESSED (DOWN): < BUTTON="+getKey(keycode)+" ID="+keycode+" KEY VALUE= "+Keypad.key(keycode)+"/>");
        return false;
    }



public boolean keyRepeat(int keycode, int time) { 
    System.out.println("KEY REPEAT: < BUTTON="+getKey(keycode)+" ID="+keycode+"/>");
    return false;
}

public boolean keyStatus(int keycode, int time) {
    System.out.println("KEY STATUS: < BUTTON="+getKey(keycode)+" ID="+keycode+"/>");
    return false;
}

public boolean keyUp(int keycode, int time) {
    System.out.println("KEY PRESSED (UP): < BUTTON="+getKey(keycode)+" ID="+keycode+" KEY VALUE= "+Keypad.key(keycode)+"/>");
    return false;
}

public String getKey(int keycode){
    System.out.println("[EVENT ID] = "+ keycode);
    //Converts the provided keycode into a value which can be compared to the keypad 
    //constants
    keycode = Keypad.key(keycode);

    System.out.println("[KEY ID] = "+ keycode);

    String Result = null;
    switch (keycode) {
    case Keypad.KEY_ALT:
        Result = "ALT";
        break;
    case Keypad.KEY_BACKLIGHT:
            Result = "BACKLIGHT";
            break;
    case Keypad.KEY_BACKSPACE:
        Result = "BACKSPACE";
        break;
    case Keypad.KEY_BACKWARD:
        Result = "BACKWARD";
        break;
    case Keypad.KEY_CAMERA_FOCUS:
        Result = "CAMERA_FOCUS";
        break;
    case Keypad.KEY_MIDDLE:
        Result = "CONVENIENCE_1";
        break;
    case Keypad.KEY_CONVENIENCE_2:
        Result = "CONVENIENCE_2";
        break;
    case Keypad.KEY_DELETE:
        Result = "DELETE";
        break;
    case Keypad.KEY_END:
        Result = "END_CALL_BUTTON";
        break;
    case Keypad.KEY_ENTER:
        Result = "ENTER";
        break;
    case Keypad.KEY_ESCAPE:
        Result = "ESCAPE";
        break;
    case Keypad.KEY_FORWARD:
        Result = "FORWARD";
        break;
    case Keypad.KEY_LOCK:
        Result = "LOCK";
        break;
    case Keypad.KEY_MENU:
        Result = "MENU";
        break;

    case Keypad.KEY_NEXT:
        Result = "NEXT";
        break;
    case Keypad.KEY_RIGHT_3:
        Result = "RIGHT_3";
        break;
    case Keypad.KEY_SEND:
        Result = "DIAL";
        break;
    case Keypad.KEY_SHIFT_LEFT:
        Result = "SHIFT_LEFT";
        break;
    case Keypad.KEY_SHIFT_RIGHT:
        Result = "SHIFT_RIGHT";
        break;
    case Keypad.KEY_SHIFT_X:
        Result = "SHIFT_X";
        break;
    case Keypad.KEY_SPACE:
        Result = "SPACE";
        break;
    case Keypad.KEY_SPEAKERPHONE:
        Result = "SPEAKERPHONE";
        break;
    case Keypad.KEY_VOLUME_DOWN:
        Result = "VOLUME_DOWN";
        break;
    case Keypad.KEY_VOLUME_UP:
        Result = "VOLUME_UP";
        break;
    default:
        Result = null;
        break;
    }

    return Result;
}
```

}